# Page background image scaling for different resolution devices

Tags: ios, css, cordova, background-image, screen-resolution

Here is what I need to do. I need to make a mobile app for ipad and iphone using phonegap and I need to set image background to all pages in the application. I was thinking to use a .png image in high resolution (the highest one I will be supporting), but I am not sure how to handle image re-sizing when the aspect ration is not kept. For example if I use image that is 1136X640 (iphone5) how it will look on iphone4 (res: 960 x 640). Or should I check the device and provide different images for different devices? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the image as background in CSS like this :

```
body{
    background-image:url('your_url');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

This way it will fill your body

Comment: If I use this, which size should I use for image? These devices have different resolutions and ppi as well?

Comment: Any resolution will work, the image will be either zoomed in or out if needed.

Comment: Ok, thank u. I guess it is better to use high resolution and zoom it out?

Comment: Yes this way the device with greater resolution won't see bad quality image

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size` propery in css3

e.g.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

IE hack (for lower than IE9)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

It fits background image to your screen & still maintain aspect ratio of image.

Here is a good tutorial for you, [**Click Here**](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)